# How to escape double quote in the json

Tags: java, json

I get data from external json source, which is like below

```
{"root":{"name":"Haf"eez","skills":["java","j2ee","jquery","ext-js"]}}
```

How to parse this in java. The word Hafeez has double quote in the center.

After escaping the above i would do

```
  jsonObject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(
            new InputStreamReader(input)));
```

Comment: Basically the double quote needs to be escaped before parsing.

Comment: That's invalid JSON. fix the external source

Comment: You are receiving broken json from another service?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.  Contact the external source and tell them to send actual JSON.

Comment: I have done that. But they don't agree to correct that :(

Comment: Basically the patterns {“
“}
[“
“]
“:
:”
,“
“,
are valid is what i understood.

Comment: If you want to try escaping quotes beside these patterns `{“` `“}` `[“` `“]` `“:` `:”` `,“` `“,` then you can try with `yourData.replaceAll("(?<![{\\[:,])\"(?![}\\]:,])", "\\\\\"")`. But what about cases where quote that needs to be escpated has one of JSon meta-characters near? Regex may not be the best tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash to escape. Replace " with \\"

Using regex: `str.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z0-9])(\")([a-zA-Z0-9])", "$1\\\\\\\\\"$3");`

Comment: I believe i have to apply some regex to escape this

Comment: Yes, you can check that " is preceded and followed by a non-syntax character - not sure if that would work in all cases for you.

Comment: What if JSon will look like `{"name":"value", with" lots "of "["quotes"]" "("and "some special marks")"}`? Regex may not be best option here.

Comment: I agree, but if that is what the external provides and he can't make them use proper syntax then it's kludging time :P

Comment: @user1794566 Sure, use regex if you want additional problems.